# Django cannot unpack non-iterable 'Q' object

Tags: django

Im trying to use Q to make query in django. Database im using for this class is PostgreSQL.

My model is:

```
class DataSetPG(models.Model):
tower_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)
value = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('tower_code',)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.tower_code
```

My view is asking for:

```
DataSetPG.objects.filter(Q(tower_code="something"))
```

But i got this error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Q object
```

What I'm doing wrong?  I tried .get instead of .filter and many many other kinds of stuff, but nothing. Im also using Q for querying in mongo database and works fine.

Comment: Just some more info. Using the normal query works:
DataSetPG.objects.filter(tower_code="port525")

Comment: Just in case, what class are you importing for Q?

Comment: @17slim yes thats the problem, im importing: mongoengine.queryset.visitor How can i use two Q' from different classes?

Comment: `from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q as MongoQ` and `from django.db.models import Q as DjangoQ`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting my comment as an answer:

You can't use the Mongo Q as a Django Q to my understanding. You should instead import like so:

```
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q as MongoQ
from django.db.models import Q as DjangoQ
```

With this, instead of `Q(tower_code='something')` use `DjangoQ(tower_code='something')`. Wherever you used the Q from mongoengine, replace it with MongoQ.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I was already desperate with this and didn't pay attention to the import. Thank you.